# How do implement tree nodes using Spring Security ACL?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I'm developing an application using spring 4.0.6 and Hibernate 4.2.21. I have an entity as follow:

```
public class A {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<A> children = new HashSet<A>(0);

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private A parent;

   /*
    *
    * Getters And Setters
    */

}
```

In another words, `A` entity is a tree. Now I want to secure all nodes of tree.  Consider the following tree:

```
Node-1   
   Node-1.1
      Node-1.1.1
      Node-1.1.2
   Node-1.2
   Node-1.3
Node-2
Node-3
   Node-3.1
   Node-3.2
   Node-3.3
```

I secure node as follow:

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
public List<A> getAll() {}
```

This code secure nodes in first level(`Node-1`, `Node-2` & `Node-3`). Now we want to get a user `read` acccess in `Node-1`, `Node-1.1` & `Node-1-2` nodes. How do we implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACL inheritance. You'll have to add an `ObjectIdentity` for each child. Note that `acl_object_identity` table has `parent_object` and `entries_inheriting` attributes.

Unrelated, if you are using application level filtering of large collections you should think about creating specifications which join with ACL entities so you can utilise database filtering which would improve the performance.

Comment: I add all nodes to acl tables, But What is `parent_object` and `entries_inheriting` roles?

Comment: `parent_object` is the ID of first-level node for all second-level nodes and `entries_inheriting` must be set to true if you want them to have the same permissions as the parent. For the third-level nodes you have to specify ID of the second-level node from which are they inheriting.

Comment: When you use `@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")`, Acl only check first-level nodes and it does not work with child. Is it a good idea to define `@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")` at entity class for `getNodes` method?